# Autohotkey function variables bugged?

Tags: function, autohotkey

I have a problem passing variables to functions. They seem to just stop working. Can someone explain why this example works like it does: it only shows "equal outside" box to me (basically,when passed,comparison stops working)?

```
Test(var)
{
    PixelGetColor, bar, 2,2
    if bar!=var
    {
        MsgBox, color %bar% inside != %var%
    }
}

!t::
PixelGetColor, foo, 2,2
Test(foo)
return
```

Edit: Replaced the code with a working one

Comment: That's because you are not comparing `bar` to the variable `var` you are comparing `bar` to the literal string "var", add '%' around var and everything will work as expected. or better use expression if with parenthesis.

Comment: The code you posted earlier had a space in the function definition `TestComp (var) ` this is illegal in autohotkey. if it worked for you it means that you had another function called TestComp.

Comment: Oleg, thanks! But why does it work outside of a function? Why comparing outside of a function without % works but inside does not?

Comment: In your current code you are not comparing anything outside a function, show me code that doesn't work and I will explain why.

Comment: thank you, I understand now why it didn't work. Indeed, I have to use % otherwise autohotkey cannot distinguish between var name and string literal. I thought if you can do "bar = foo + 1" and it properly gets value out of foo, then you can also do "bar = foo" and that will work too

Comment: `bar = foo + 1` will also just set the string "foo + 1" to bar. Autohotkey has 2 different assignment operators, `bar := foo + 1` (**note** the **:** before **=**) will evaluate the expression `foo + 1` and assign it to bar, that's probably what you did.

Answer (score 0):

it works both way for me? when i click atl+t msgbox said equal outside and then equal inside as it should have happened? first you define function but not use it. next fraction of code is executed by hotkey and there is regular condition which fulfills and msgbox says equal outside, and only after that you are calling the function which should say equal inside, if you had done like this it would say equal inside first and then equal outside.

```
TestComp(var)
{
If var=0xffffff
{
MsgBox, equal Inside
}
}
foo = 0xffffff
TestComp(foo)
!t::
foo = 0xffffff
If foo=0xffffff
{
MsgBox, equal Outside
}

return
```

pardon me if i am wrong in any case

Comment: I am sorry I must have erred somewhere. I swear an identical code I used to test this bug did not work but I've since deleted it, and typed this one from memory. I have now tested and indeed it works. However, the original bug was with getting pixel colors. I've typed another example and tested it myself. Basically, if I call PixelGetColor inside a function, it doesn't compare with function var. This example code (updated OP) should say that two same values are not equal. Please test it and see.

Comment: give me code and i will test it but first try and make variable global out of every function, before assignment.